# Download functionality in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, download

I had checked that initMouseEvent is now deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

Now I need to activate via other alternative :
I tried :

```
`link`http://jsfiddle.net/8wos7cf8/7/: 
 here: link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
```

but this loc not working for me.
Can you help me regarding to this?

Comment: Try [Brython](http://www.brython.info/)

Comment: Try to read some comment here [Best way to integrate Python code with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916244/best-way-to-integrate-python-code-with-html)

Comment: @Max ,JasonEstiberio Is django is better solution and thank you guys for your help.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro Yes my problem is half solved.Actually I have multiple checkbox in my html page.I want to write a few values attached with that checkbox in text file while button of html page is clicked.Is there any solution regarding to it.

Comment: You need to have a better understanding between [client and server side programming](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/171210). If you want to build a simple small web app then use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) instead of Django.

Comment: Brython works on the client side. If you want to fetch values of multiple checkbox to the server to store it in a txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems obvoius, but here it is:

Old:

```
children = elem.getchildren()
```

New:

```
children = list(elem)
```